# Bitmap ctor throws an exception

Tags: vb.net

I can't figure out the solution. This is my code:

```
   Dim wbRect As Rectangle = WebBrowser1.ClientRectangle
   Dim wbBm As New Bitmap(WebBrowser1.ClientRectangle.Width, WebBrowser1.ClientRectangle.Height)
   Dim gwb As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(wbBm)
   gwb.CopyFromScreen(WebBrowser1.PointToScreen(New Point(14, 31)),
   New Point(0, 0),
   New Size(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height))
   wbBm.Save("c:\temp1.bmp")
   PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "c:\temp1.bmp"
   PictureBox1.BringToFront()

   Dim bm As New Bitmap("c:\img1.bmp") //here appears an error - Parameter is not valid

   Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height)
   Dim bmpData As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = bm.LockBits(rect, _
   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
```

What could I do to remove the error?

Comment: You could start by telling us what the Exception is.

Comment: Did you look at the InnerException ?

Comment: I'm assuming that the strings are okay in VB without escaping \`\\\` or literal `@` indication ...???

Comment: In the InnerException tab it says "Nothing"...
    at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename) - maybe it helps

Comment: It's created at the start of the code

Comment: No it is not.  `temp1.bmp` is created in the code above.

Comment: In code I can see only the creation of `temp1.bmp`, but you try to read an `img1.bmp` file.

Comment: Steve, I just did the stupidest mistake in the history of programming...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this error if the file does not exist.  Check to make sure img1.bmp exists before you try and open it:

```
    Dim fn As String = "c:\img1.bmp"
    If File.Exists(fn)
        Dim bm As New Bitmap(fn) ''here appears an error - Parameter is not valid

        Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height)
        Dim bmpData As System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData = bm.LockBits(rect, _
        System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    End If
```